# Which Diode With This Regulator

Tags: voltage-regulator, diodes

In its datasheet there is no indication or explanation which diode to use.
Datasheet page 10 have application circuit.I will use to regulate around 10-15 voltage to fix 5 volts. I chose **B230A-13-F Schottky diode** which has:

- Voltage - DC Reverse (Vr) (Max):30v
- Current - Average Rectified (Io) : 2A

Could you inform me if it is okay or not.

[Datasheet link](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/AP3211.pdf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RdsOn on IC is 0.35 Ω and ESR on Diode is less so OK   @ 0.1 Ω  from VI curve slope.

Answer (score 0):

In an asynchronous buck converter, the catch diode needs to be rated for the full load current and input voltage. You have 50% margin on voltage and 25% margin on current. The diode you've selected should be fine.